# Outline the symbolism of “The astronaut in Isolation” by Rosalind Morris

Tags: poetry, symbolism, rosalind-c-morris

“The astronaut in Isolation” by Rosalind Morris is a poem that was published on [*Daily Maverick* on 30 April 2020](https://www.dailymaverick.co.za/article/2020-04-30-unlocked-poems-for-critical-times-part-nine/).
It's a new poem and there is no interpretation of this anywhere on the web. I would like the poem's symbolism and the spaces in lines 9 & 10 (quoting lines 7-10 here):

> the sound of leafstorm,
>
> dreams of turning his face
>
> to the sun,
>
> and       for a moment